# is_post_type_archive not working in feed

Tags: plugins, custom-post-type-archives, podcasting

I'm trying to alter a feed for my plugin's custom post type to add lines for podcasting.  Here is the code I've got right now:

```
add_action ('init', 'my_plugin_init');

function my_plugin_init() {
    if ( is_post_type_archive('my_plugin_custom_type') ) {
        add_action('rss2_ns', 'my_plugin_podcast_ns');
    }
}

function my_plugin_podcast_ns() {
    echo 'xmlns:itunes="http://www.itunes.com/dtds/podcast-1.0.dtd"';
}
```

The archive for this post type is located at `http://example.com/custom_type/`, and I'm getting the feed at `http://example.com/custom_type/feed/`.  However, my extra line is not showing up.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Changing the if conditional to `get_post_type() == 'my_plugin_custom_type'` doesn't work, either.  Removing the if statement and unconditionally adding the `rss2_ns` action does produce the line in the feed, as expected.

Comment: `'init'` is probably too early to get a meaningful result from `is_post_type_archive()` which depends on the the query having been run. ['template_redirect'](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/template_redirect) is probably the earliest action you could run it.

Comment: @CharlesClarkson, that worked.  Thanks!  If you post it as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`'init'` is probably too early to get a meaningful result from `is_post_type_archive()` which depends on the the query having been run. `'template_redirect'` is probably the earliest action you could run it.

Comment: Just a follow up: The `'pre_get_posts'` action hook is earlier than `'template_redirect'`. It runs after the `is_post_type_archive()` conditional tag is set, and before the query is run.  [Ref question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/110195/32110)

Answer (score 1):

On WordPress 5.x+ : The `'wp'` action works as a place to catch query dependent conditions. For example `is_post_type_archive()` as a condition successfully and then set the cookie. `'pre_get_posts'` at least in my case did not work. ([source](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/208868/manipulating-cookie-on-specific-taxonomy-archive-page))

e.g.:

`add_action( 'wp', 'set_archive_cookie');`

From Codex: More about [actions](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference). More about the [`'wp'` action](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp).