# Find out if request is for custom post type archive before query runs

Tags: plugins, wp-query, hooks, custom-post-type-archives

I am writing a plugin that is modifying the RSS2 feed for a podcast that uses a custom post type.

After the query runs (on action hook `template_redirect`; See [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/109471/32110) for why), I'm checking to see if the request is for an archive of my custom post type.  If so, I add actions and filters to modify the RSS2 template.

Now I would like to make some modifications that affect the query.  Without using the `is_post_type_archive` function, which is only updated after the query runs, how do I check that the request is for an archive of the custom post type?  On which hook would I add this?

Here is the relevant code I have so far:

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'myplugin_frontend_init_after_query');

function myplugin_frontend_init_after_query() {
    if ( is_post_type_archive('myplugin_custom_type') ) {
        add_action('rss2_ns', 'myplugin_podcast_ns');
        add_action('rss2_head', 'myplugin_podcast_head');
        add_filter('the_excerpt_rss', 'myplugin_podcast_description_filter');
        // other actions and filters here
        // The next one is the one I'm having trouble with:
        add_filter('option_posts_per_rss', 'myplugin_podcast_number_filter');
        // I'm attempting to alter the number of posts in the feed, but of course after the query runs, it is too late.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the hook `pre_get_post` see [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts)

Comment: Nice! And as a bonus, the `is_post_type_archive` function works there as well, so I can just move the entire thing from the `template_redirect` hook to the `pre_get_post` hook.  Thanks.