# Manipulating cookie on specific taxonomy archive page

Tags: custom-taxonomy, conditional-tags, cookies

I have this code to set cookie when user on the taxonomy archive page called 'term-country'

```
if (is_tax('term-country'))
add_action('init', 'my_setcookie');

// my_setcookie() set the cookie on the domain and directory WP is installed on
function my_setcookie(){
    $path = parse_url(get_option('siteurl'), PHP_URL_PATH);
     $host = parse_url(get_option('siteurl'), PHP_URL_HOST);
     $expiry = strtotime('+1 month');
     setcookie('location', 'my_cookie_value_3', $expiry, $path, $host);
}
```

when I add the is_tax() function the code will not work 
when I remove the is_tax() function the code will work

is there any issues with my code ?

Comment: Have you tried any other methods? Like is_archive().

Comment: `is_tax` won't work before `wp` action, the query has to run before conditionals will work.

Comment: @Nath no I did not.

Comment: @Milo can I still use is_tax function and then instead of using add_action I will use jquery to set the cookie ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After googling around I found the correct way to do it by using the 'wp' hook

if (is_tax('term-country'))

add_action('wp', 'my_setcookie');
// my_setcookie() set the cookie on the domain and directory WP is installed on
function my_setcookie(){
    $path = parse_url(get_option('siteurl'), PHP_URL_PATH);
     $host = parse_url(get_option('siteurl'), PHP_URL_HOST);
     $expiry = strtotime('+1 month');
     setcookie('location', 'my_cookie_value_3', $expiry, $path, $host);
}